# Conviction about a system from pseudo-proofs of its truths

Tags: logic, fallacies, argumentation

I vaguely recall a description about manifestations of the truths offered by a system being pseudo-proofs for that system to be right, in a context in which logical certainty is not possible. Consider the following examples:

> A theory (e.g. "*those who open doors with the left hand are less
>   prone to falling to the ground*"), which cannot be definitely proven,
>   but can't be proven wrong either, is propounded, even if absurd.
>   Manifestations of the predictions of the theory would not be real
>   proofs, but could still convince.
>
> It is not possible to clearly know whether Physics are right. The
>   creations of technology, based on the knowledge it provides, work, so
>   Physics *seem* right -- although such intuition cannot be proven.

For what it is worth, I remember this conviction taking place where the success of someone would convince others to follow him or her. However, I do not know if it was a thought of myself or if I read it somewhere. I have tried searching, and also looked the Wikipedia pages about fallacies, but have not found it. If such pseudo-argument is recognized, how is it named?

Comment: I do not know the answer but the book, `The Structure of Scientific Revolutions` by Thomas Kuhn speaks a lot about - and demonstrates incredible insight into how the paradigms created from such pseudo-proofs gain traction and become essentially  infallible.

Comment: @user1167442 Thanks :). Although the book (judging from the relevant Wikipedia page, I have not read it) covers a similar topic, it is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well; still a highly stimulating read if you have the leisure.